# consider the following statements regarding the smallest interior angle of a n sided polygon with perimeter n units and with maximum area?

Tags: geometry, contest-math, polygons, angle

let(f) be the relation defined by f(n) = The smallest interior angle value of the n sided polygon with perimeter n units with maximum area, for each positive integer n(>2).which of the following are true?

1. given two positive integers n,m(<2) with n> m always have that f(n)>f(m)
2. Given a positive integers n we always have that the difference between f(n) and f(n+1) is less than 45°.
3. there are two distinct positive integers n,m(>2) such that the difference between f(n) and f(m) is less than 1°.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an $n$-sided polygon with a given perimeter, the regular polygon has the maximum area.

Thus, for a regular $n$-sided polygon, all the interior angles are equal and are equal to
$$f(n)=\frac{180^o(n-2)}{n}=180^o(1-\frac2n)$$

Clearly, $f(n)$ increases when $n$ increases.

Now,
$$f(n+1)-f(n)=180^o(1-\frac2{n+1}-1+\frac2n)=360^o\frac1{n(n+1)}$$

It can be shown using induction that the above is less than $45^o$ for all $n\ge3$.

Finally,
$$f(n)-f(m)=180^o(1-\frac2n-1+\frac2m)=360^o\frac{(n-m)}{nm}$$
Let
$$f(n)-f(m)<1^o$$
Let $n=m+1$. Then,
$$360^o\frac{(n-m)}{nm}=360^o\frac1{m(m+1)}<1^o$$
$$m^2+m-360>0$$
This inequality clearly has positive integer solutions.